# Entity Framework: insert into a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many

Why A and B in a many-to-many relationship, when inserting record to A table, a new record will be added in B table as well?

There are two model classes, `Customer` and `Course`. One customer can choose many courses. Also, one course can be chosen by many customers.

The problem I met is that when I create a customer with some courses he selected (for example `course1` and `course2`), `course1` and `course2` are already in the `Courses` table, but it will automatically insert `course1` and `course2` again which is not what I want.

**Customer** class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Range(16,58)]
    public int  Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Course> CoursesEnrolled { get; set; }
}
```

**Course** class:

```
public class Course
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)] 
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`CustomerController`, `Save` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save( Customer customer 
{
        if (customer.Id == 0)
        {
            Customer customerInDb = new Customer()
            {
                Name = customer.Name , 
                City = customer.City ,
                Age = customer.Age ,
                Gender = customer.Gender ,
                CoursesEnrolled =  customer.CoursesEnrolled 
            };

            _context.Customers.Add(customerInDb);
        }
        else
        {
            var customerInDb = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == customer.Id);

            if (customerInDb == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            customerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
            customerInDb.Age = customer.Age;
            customerInDb.City = customer.City;
            customerInDb.Gender = customer.Gender;
            customerInDb.CoursesEnrolled = customer.CoursesEnrolled;
        }

        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            Exception raise = dbEx;

            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }

            throw raise;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index" , "Customer");
}
```

Four courses exist in the `Courses` table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ktTd.png)

When I create a customer with some courses selected, `Customer` saves successfully, and `CustomersCourses` also added the data.

But in the `Courses` table, the selecting courses that the customer enrolled also are added to the courses table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kupfE.png)

The data in the red triangle is not we want.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I guess it's all about what you have in `customer.CoursesEnrolled` and how you filled that. If there are no existing course id's in there, they are of course new courses. But you do not show us that information so we have to guess...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason is just like ashin said and he gave two solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use new instances of Courses (with the same ID as that of the persisted record in the database) every time a new Customer instance is created. EF tracks them as a newly added objects and inserts them to db as new records on save changes. There are a couple of options:

1. Load Courses from the context and add them to the CoursesEnrolled collection of the customer instance, which lets EF know that the entity is already persisted in the database.
2. Explcitly mark the CoursesEnrolled as Unchanged/Detached so that EF would skip it.

   ```
   foreach (var course in customerInDb.CoursesEnrolled)
   {
     _context.Entry(course).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried these two solutions you offer , both of them works fine. Thanks for that.